# .htaccess in hosting ready for certbot

Tags: certbot

I am trying to prepare hosting for certbot to get SSL certificate.

I understand that for certbot query for address

domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/something

in my domain I have to return word something or whatever certbot sends to my API.

I am trying to intercept that word, pass it to php and return that word to certbot.

I am trying to make .htaccess file for apache server with following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^.well-known(.*)$ wp/$1 [R=277,L]
</IfModule>
```

Once I do it I get right 277 response BUT once I insert into .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/.well-known/a(.*)$ wp/$1 [R=277,L]
</IfModule>
```

It returns 404 not found error because of slash after word known.

HOW TO MAKE APACHE UNDERSTAND THAT SLASH TO RETURN ME

277 ERROR CODE for second .htaccess file content same as it does for first .htaccess content?

By the way I am using certbot on linux to get Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on HOSTING with no VPS

I tried different .htaccess contents but neither worked for me.
I have to get the code sent by CERTBOT from URL and pass code from URL to php page for example. THAT php page would return code in its content to CERTBOT. CertBot passes code in URL so I have to make .htaccess file to extract code from URL and pass it to php page.

Comment: but why are you making mess with a reason? I mean you don't have to make changes to your htaccess file to get SSL certificate!

Comment: You can follow the guide available [here](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/Simple-guide-to-add-TLS-cert-to-cpanel) to get LetsEncrypt SSL on a shared hosting/cPanel with terminal access.